# PySide : How to get a QTabWidget to resize with the window?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I'm quite new to Python, and I'm developing an app with the PySide library.

I have a `QTabWidget` in which I will later define buttons/labels/... with some layouts. The question is simple : **I'd like to have my active tab filling the window horizontally and vertically, even when I resize the window.** For now its size is determined by the widgets I put in. Even with `addStretch(1)` in a `QHBoxLayout` or `QVBoxLayout` I can't get it to expand.

Is there an easy way to do this (I'm not a Python expert yet) ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main window is QMainWindow then it is enough to insert QTabWidget with `mainwindow->setCentralWidget()` - by default it will use all available space.

In other case, to have QTabWidget to follow the resizing/geometry change of parent widget, it is enough to make some layout on the parent widget and just insert QTabWidget there.

Code is approx (in Qt):

```
QWidget * dialog = ...
QTabWidget * tabs = new QTabWidget;
QVBoxLayout * vbox = new QVBoxLayout;
vbox->addWidget(tabs);

dialog->setLayout(vbox);
dialog->show();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works perfectly : I was so concentrated on the layout of the tabs, I forgot the layout of the `QTabWidget`...